# Cannot save object when I get date from datepicker and parse it in groovy

Tags: grails, groovy, datepicker

I am new in groovy on grails. I use datepicker in GSP page. When I use it to get a date and parse it in server side, the object can't be saved.

My Domain is

```
class PurchaseOrder {
    Date orderDate;
    Date deliveryDate;
    Double totalQuantity;
    Double deliveredQuantity;
    Double totalCost;
    Long totalItem;
    Long deliveredTotalItem;
    Long requisition

    static belongsTo = [branch:OrganizationalBranch,orderedBy: Employee, supplier: Supplier]
    static hasMany = [itemDetails:OrderDetails]



    static constraints = {
        deliveryDate(nullable: true);
        deliveredQuantity(nullable: true);
        deliveredTotalItem(nullable: true);

        itemDetails(nullable: true);
        orderDate(nullable: true);
        totalItem(nullable: true);
        totalQuantity(nullable: true);
        totalCost(nullable: true);
    }
}
```

My GSP is :

```
<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: purchaseOrderInstance, field: 'deliveryDate', 'error')} ">
    <label for="deliveryDate">
        <g:message code="purchaseOrder.deliveryDate.label" default="Delivery Date" />

    </label>
    <g:field type="deliveryDate" id="deliveryDate" name="deliveryDate" class="datepicker" />

</div>
```

And code of Controller is :

```
try {
            String orderDateSt = params?.deliveryDate
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy")
            def orderDate = new Date().parse("MM/dd/yyyy", orderDateSt.trim())           
            purchaseOrderInstance.deliveryDate = orderDate
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.getMessage()
            ex.printStackTrace()
        }
```

The error is :

```
purchase.PurchaseOrderController  - Field error in object 'com.sb.ims.purchase.PurchaseOrder' on field 'deliveryDate': rejected value [06/30/2016]; codes [com.sb.ims.purchase.PurchaseOrder.deliveryDate.typeMismatch.error,com.sb.ims.purchase.PurchaseOrder.deliveryDate.typeMismatch,purchaseOrder.deliveryDate.typeMismatch.error,purchaseOrder.deliveryDate.typeMismatch,typeMismatch.com.sb.ims.purchase.PurchaseOrder.deliveryDate,typeMismatch.deliveryDate,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch]; arguments [deliveryDate]; default message [Unparseable date: "06/30/2016"]
```

How can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your Grails version is >= 2.3, you should be able to use `BindingFormat` annotation instead of parsing the date in your controller:

import org.grails.databinding.BindingFormat

```
class PurchaseOrder { 
    @BindingFormat('MM/dd/yyyy') 
    Date orderDate
    @BindingFormat('MM/dd/yyyy')
    Date deliveryDate
    ....
}
```

Comment: he can also globally configure it with property `grails.databinding.dateFormats`